# What are Feature Phone(non-smart phones) Html/CSS Basic features and DocTypes?

Tags: html, css

I am starting development on a feature phone web site for the first time and I am unfamiliar with the waters.  I have done some research, but generally the google searches are vague as I imagine the development of it as well.  The questions are as of follows:

I want to cover as many feature phones as possible, but I need to know the following features are generally available:

Is this a good doctype?

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11.dtd">`

Are they able to link a stylesheet?

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Can it use the following css attributes?

```
background-color, margin, padding, text-align, font
```

What type of images can it support?

`jpg, gif, png`

Do I have to resort to table layouts?

I know these questions maybe answered with a test with a 10 year old phone, but I don't have access to any feature phones.  I was hoping to find some answers here before I jump start too far into development.

Comment: What's a feature phone?

Comment: Any phone with very little features?  or was that a joke? :)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_phone

Comment: No, Never heard of that term.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't either until today, but that's what they call non-smartphones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your definition of support. If you want the content to be accessible, then I would suggest that you aim low. Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` and stick to minimal styles (or none at all). I'm assuming this is an old 3G flip phone, or something from that era. I would keep backgrounds and colors simple, and use very basic, clear styling that only enhances the experience without breaking. In other words, use colors and images sparingly. You want clear focus of content and navigation, as users will be navigating with a d-pad style cursor, and may lack the ability to select text or see URLs before clicking. I would also assume that the device will be slow, and somewhat cumbersome. Images (especially backgrounds) will only get in the way, and may slow the browser down to the point of becoming unresponsive if the page is too heavy.

I've never tested anything for this type of device, so I'm basing my suggestions anecdotally on lowest common denominator factors.

Comment: I think your answer is the closest one to answer.  I just wanted to know kinda what should be used.  Although the answer is not correct and my question completely is a bit vague because I wasn't sure of the requirements.  There is no way of knowing, but for the most part once the phone doesn't have a feature and it gets below 150x150 res.  I think styling doesn't even matter at that point.  I think as long as the the textual areas for navigation and content are still there, its good.

Answer (score 2):

As "feature phone" is a term for an entire class of devices which run all sorts of different software, there is no single answer here. Indeed, many feature phones don't have web browsers at all.

You will need to pick a few specific featurephone browsers you want your site to work with and test against those.